# Why docker buildx binaries cannot build window container?

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, binaries, buildx

I am running Docker binaries on Window and not using Docker Desktop.

I have install docker-buildx.exe from https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases

When running build command from Dockerfile for a Window container, the docker daemon reply that:

```
docker build -t image:v1 .
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: failed to mount in-place: {bind ... [rbind ro]}: invalid windows mount type: 'bind'
```

My Dockerfile's content:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809

ARG http_proxy
ARG https_proxy

ENTRYPOINT [ "ping", "-t", "localhost" ]
```

I have search for some solution but they only support docker engine which installed by Docker Desktop. Is there any solutions for this case?
Note: I want to use Docker binaries for my personal purpose and cannot use Docker Desktop